# Any way to make my code shorter to perhaps to 2 variebles while still keeping it to 2 decimals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make my code shorter just a few points away from #1.

I tried shrinking it but its just too complicated.

```
Taxers = int(input("Will you be eating in 1 For Yes 2 For No:"))
TotalCostA = TotalCostB * 0.05
Tax = TotalCostA
TotalCostF = "{:.2f}".format(Tax)
TotalCostT = Tax + TotalCostB
if Taxers == 2:
    print("Tax = 0")
    print("Your total pizza cost it", TotalCostB, "kd")
else:
    print("Tax = ", TotalCostF)
    print("Your total pizza cost it", TotalCostT, "kd")
```

Comment: For a start, what's the point of `Tax = TotalCostA`?

Comment: Its to take the answer of TotalCostA and change it into a variable so it can be formatted to 2 decimal places in the line under it

Comment: Never mind the code length; your program is broken. `TotalCostB` doesn't exist, it does unexpected things when entering numbers other than 1 or to and completely breaks when you don't enter a number.

Comment: `TotalCostB = (TotPep + TotMarg + TotMush)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the extra variables and use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) for a slightly more fluent experience:

```py
Taxers = int(input("Will you be eating in 1 For Yes 2 For No:"))
TotalCostA = TotalCostB * 0.05
TotalCostT = TotalCostA + TotalCostB
if Taxers == 2:
    print("Tax = 0")
    print(f"Your total pizza cost it {TotalCostB} kd")
else:
    print(f"Tax = {TotalCostA:.2f}")
    print(f"Your total pizza cost it {TotalCostT} kd")
```

Shortening it even further will reduce code readability. On that note, I strongly recommend you to follow the Python naming conventions and improve the variable names to something more descriptive, e.g. `cost_with_tax`.

Comment: interesting I will for sure do that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the text printed while taking input and returning output, here is my attempt. I think you have not defined `TotalCostB`, so change accordingly.

```py
print(["Tax = 0"+"\nYour total pizza cost it "+str(TotalCostB)+" kd","Tax = "+"{:.2f}".format(TotalCostB * 0.05)+"\nYour total pizza cost it "+"{:.2f}".format(TotalCostB * 1.05)+" kd"][int(input("Will you be eating in 1 For Yes 2 For No:")) == 2])
```

Comment: What happens if the input is not a number?

Comment: why would you combine string formatting using `format()` with adding strings via the `+` operator? You can easily combine that.

Comment: `Tax = 0.45Your total pizza cost it 9.45 kd` know how to make a space ?

Comment: When I choose 2 this is what happens `Tax = 0+/n Your total pizza cost it 9.0 kd`

Comment: Made changes to correct it.

Comment: That is terribly unreadable

Comment: Sorry, I thought the goal was to reduce the code size while retaining the functionality.

Comment: The point of short code is that it's easier to understand. But at some point, shorter code will be harder to understand as your example demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about making your code more robust (which involves more code) then you can start thinking about simplification.

Consider this:

```
tax = {1: 0.05, 2: 0.00}
pizzacost = 4.00
while True:
    userinput = input('Will you be eating in 1 For Yes 2 For No: ')
    try:
        if (inorout := int(userinput)) in tax:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(f'Tax = {tax[inorout] * pizzacost:.2f}kd\nYour total pizza cost is {pizzacost * (1 + tax[inorout]):.2f}kd')
```

Comment: im not trying to change anything and I have a valid solution but thanks for answering